# Data from one component into another through the const?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react js and I am trying to get the data/state from component A into component B, I know it sounds easy but I tried many examples and couldn't make it. The problem is a bit different: I tried createContenxt

```
export const AContext = React.createContext('test');
class A extends Component {
      constructor(props){
          this.state = { id: this.props.aStore.id()}}

     if login success go to component C:
       <AContext.Provider value="test">
       <Route render={(props) => <C {...props} id={this.state} />} />
       </AContext.Provider>

class C extends Component {
      <Sidebar routes={dashboard}>

const dashboard = {path: "/b",
  sidebarName: "b",
  navbarName: "b",
  icon: IconDashboard,
  component: B}

import {AContext} from './A';
class B extends Component {
  static contextType = AContext;

render(){ console.log(this.context)} //=> empty object
```

Here is an idea of how the code is working, now I have to get the id into component B, I managed to pass it through C but how can I pass it to const dashboard and component B?

Comment: You need to read a lot start from here https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: I was doing the examples from the documentation but still didn't manage to solve the problem.

Comment: try using "createContext" api from React v16.8

Comment: I just tried now: inside the component A I done: export const CContext = React.createContext('0'); and in the login pass as <CContext.Provider value={'test'}> <Route.../> /> in the  component B I am importing the context and have static contextType = CContext and when I am trying to see the log using this.context got an empty object.

Comment: "through the const"? you mean "through Context?"

Comment: I done some modifications, as rohit said to pass it through Context, but is still not working.

Comment: I tried to update everything, and now I have a problem with the component B, store problem because I am using connect. I pass store={store} in the AProvider

Answer (score 0):

It's better to structure your React page like this:

```
return(
    <div>
        { shouldGoHere ? <SomeComponent props={this.state.propsGoHere} /> : null }
        { shouldGoThere ? <OtherComponent props={this.state.propsGoThere} /> : null }
    </div>
)
```

However using React Router is even better

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

...

return(
    <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Route exact to="/" component={HomeComponent} props={this.state.propsGoHere} />
            <Route exact to="/otherComponent" component={OtherComponent} props={this.state.MorePropsHere} />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
)
```

Using this snippet you can easily manipulate which data goes into what component and it is also easier to navigate through your app.

Comment: I would suggest looking at this article https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-pass-props-to-components/ , since my version might not work as expected